# Why does installing Ruby with rbenv fail?

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

I followed this guide: http://samsoff.es/posts/how-to-install-ruby-193

I typed  `rbenv install 1.9.3-p125` in the console.

Ruby installs OK but when I run `ruby -v` it still says version 1.8.7.

What needs to be changed for it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to my bash_login file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the new version, one of three ways:

- temporarily: `rbenv shell 1.9.3-p125` set a .rbenv-version file in
- the current directory: `rbenv local 1.9.3-p125` set the default
- version for your user: `rbenv global 1.9.3-p125`

Comment: And, conversely, to return to a system version use `rbenv global system`, where "global" could also be "shell", "local".

Comment: Yes thats in the tutorial, I did `rbenv global 1.9.3-p125` but ruby -v still says 1.8.7?

Comment: What is the output of `rbenv version` and `rbenv versions` ?

Comment: OK this line: `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` switches the ruby version. After I type that and then `ruby -v` I get `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]` - BUT - after I restart the terminal and type ruby -v again its back to 1.8.7? What can I do to make it permanent?

Comment: looks line whatever file you put the eval stuff in isn't being loaded when your shell starts. as en experiment put `echo "hello!"` right after it and see if that is printed when you start a new window/shell/terminal.

Comment: Hm what do you mean right after? Could you write the whole command?

Comment: you can just put it on the first line of the same file -- as a test to see if that file is getting loaded at all.

Comment: I added the answer to my question. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

If the install command isn't working for you with rbenv, you have to install [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build).

Answer (score 0):

you should restart the terminal to allow rbenv

> $ exec $SHEL
>     $ ruby -v
>
> > ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]